# Noninterrupting keyevents while preserving individual keystrokes

Tags: javascript

I am designing a keyboard interface through javascript, and I want to define keystroke combinations, like shift+rightkey or ctrl+tab. But after tinkering with javascript, as seen **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Arcym/ENUj2/7/)**, I've noticed that all keyevents are interrupting. In the provided example, if you go to hit the shiftkey while holding down the rightkey, the functionality of the rightkey is interrupted!

```
v = 1; /*v is the variable of velocity.*/

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event)
{
    if(event.keyCode == 39) /*39 is the keycode of rightarrowkey.*/
    {
        //moves an element by the velocity.
        var keystroke = document.getElementById("keystroke");
        keystroke.style.left = parseInt(keystroke.style.left.slice(0,-2))+v+"px";
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 16) /*16 is the keycode of shift.*/
    {
         //increases the velocity of the element by four.
        document.getElementById("keystroke").style.borderColor = "red";
        v = 4;
    }
}, false); //but hitting the shiftkey while hitting the rightkey interrupts..!
```

I also experimented with recording all keystrokes through an object which is then iterated through at a designated interval for defined keystrokes, as seen **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Arcym/kjkCc/3/)**. But this system of handling the keyboard doesn't *preserve* the individual keystrokes; if I hit a key too fast, it may not be considered, or if I hold a key for too long, it may be overconsidered!

Comment: I doubt there's a good solution for this; you can see this behaviour in a standard text area as well, the cursor stops moving once you hit the Shift key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving it a bit of thought, I may have figured out a method to both preserve each keystroke while handling interrupting keyevents. My code is somewhat quirky, but it works well for managing the keystrokes from the users.

The solution to handling each keystroke without interruptions was through registering each keyevent within an object, as was previously suggested in my question. The code continually iterates through this object to handle any new keyevents.

But to ensure each keystroke is preserved and handled at least once, a keybinding must be registered for each keyevent. I expanded the scripting for the object to register both keystrokes as well as keybindings.

```
var kbdin =
{
    stroked: new Object(),
    upbinded: new Object(),
    downbinded: new Object(),

    downbindKeystroke: function(keycode, functionality) {this.downbinded[keycode] = functionality;},
    upbindKeystroke: function(keycode, functionality) {this.upbinded[keycode] = functionality;},
    isDownbinded: function(keycode) {return this.downbinded[keycode];},
    isUpbinded: function(keycode) {return this.upbinded[keycode];},
    isStroked: function(keycode) {return this.stroked[keycode];},

    onDownstroke: function(event)
    {
        var keycode = event.keyCode;
        if(!this.isStroked(keycode))
        {
            this.stroked[keycode] = 1;
            if(this.isDownbinded(keycode))
            {this.downbinded[keycode]();}
        }
        if(this.isDownbinded(keycode))
        {event.preventDefault();}
    },

    onUpstroke: function(event)
    {
        var keycode = event.keyCode;
        delete this.stroked[keycode];
        if(this.isUpbinded(keycode))
        {
            this.upbinded[keycode]();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    },

    handleKeystrokes: function()
    {
        for(var keycode in this.downbinded)
        {
            if(this.isStroked(keycode) > 5)
            {this.downbinded[keycode]();}
        }

        for(var keycode in this.stroked)
        {this.stroked[keycode]++;}
    }
};

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {kbdin.onUpstroke(event);}, false);
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {kbdin.onDownstroke(event);}, false);
window.setInterval(function() {kbdin.handleKeystrokes();}, 50);
```

Now both the keystrokes and keybindings are coupled together, supporting each keyevent with the functionality to both signal a keystroke and execute a keybinding. It may be a bit quirky, but this code handles noninterrupting keyevents while still preserving individual keystrokes!